# Poner una imagen en index.js en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Tengo un script que muestra este menú como pueden ver existe un pequeño espacio donde debe ir un logotipo, tengo uno ya cargado en un servidor en formato svg.

[image: Menu sin logo]

El problema es que yo no se mucho de React y no se como agregar este logo.

El código del sitio que creo controla esta sección es este, espero me puedan a ayudar indicandome como le tengo que hacer, saludos.

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";

import {
  makeStyles,
  Drawer,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  List,
  Typography,
  Divider,
  MenuItem,
  IconButton,
  Menu,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import AccountCircle from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";

import MainListItems from "./MainListItems";
import NotificationsPopOver from "../components/NotificationsPopOver";
import UserModal from "../components/UserModal";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/Auth/AuthContext";
import BackdropLoading from "../components/BackdropLoading";
import { i18n } from "../translate/i18n";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    height: "100vh",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      height: "calc(100vh - 56px)",
    },
  },

  toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 24, // keep right padding when drawer closed
  },
  toolbarIcon: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: "0 8px",
    minHeight: "48px",
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  menuButtonHidden: {
    display: "none",
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: "relative",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerPaperClose: {
    overflowX: "hidden",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9),
    },
  },
  appBarSpacer: {
    minHeight: "48px",
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    overflow: "auto",
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    display: "flex",
    overflow: "auto",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
}));
```

Actualización

Intente hacerlo así, pero no funcionó

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";

import {
  makeStyles,
  Drawer,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  List,
  Typography,
  Divider,
  MenuItem,
  IconButton,
  Menu,
  SvgIcon, // Agrega SvgIcon de Material-UI //
} from "@material-ui/core";

import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import AccountCircle from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";

import MainListItems from "./MainListItems";
import NotificationsPopOver from "../components/NotificationsPopOver";
import UserModal from "../components/UserModal";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/Auth/AuthContext";
import BackdropLoading from "../components/BackdropLoading";
import { i18n } from "../translate/i18n";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    height: "100vh",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      height: "calc(100vh - 56px)",
    },
  },

  toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 24, // keep right padding when drawer closed
  },
  toolbarIcon: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: "0 8px",
    minHeight: "48px",
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  menuButtonHidden: {
    display: "none",
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: "relative",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerPaperClose: {
    overflowX: "hidden",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9),
    },
  },
  appBarSpacer: {
    minHeight: "48px",
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    overflow: "auto",
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    display: "flex",
    overflow: "auto",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  logo: { // Agrega estilos para el logo
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

// Defini tu icono SVG como un componente de React //
const Logo = (props) => (
  <SvgIcon {...props}>
 <g id="Capa_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  <path class="fil0" d="M184.88 24.11l0.14 0.06c0.25,-0.35 2.31,-1.31 2.59,-1.38 0.14,0.28 0.29,0.48 0.47,0.75 0.41,0.61 1.55,2.67 1.8,3.31l0.39 0.91c0.35,0.77 1.13,2.84 1.37,3.74 0.17,0.67 0.39,1.35 0.56,2.02 0.73,2.94 1.46,8.35 1.09,11.5 -0.02,0.2 0.01,0.44 0,0.64 -0.02,0.27 -0.06,0.24 -0.07,0.58 -0.04,1.51 -0.88,4.92 -1.51,6.18 -0.27,0.54 -0.58,1.2 -0.91,1.68 -0.2,0.3 -0.37,0.46 -0.53,0.77l-2.25 0.2c-0.22,0.03 -0.24,-0.03 -0.42,-0.06 -0.56,-0.07 -0.56,0.08 -1.88,-0.13 -0.34,-0.05 -0.55,-0.06 -0.87,-0.13 -3.07,-0.6 -4.56,-1.33 -7.26,-2.74 -0.62,-0.32 -1.84,-1.18 -2.37,-1.58 -0.11,-0.09 -0.18,-0.12 -0.29,-0.22l-0.81 -0.69c-0.53,-0.39 -1.45,-1.5 -1.92,-2.11 -0.89,-1.17 -1.71,-2.79 -1.71,-4.37 -0.27,0.05 -2.52,1.35 -3.01,1.61 -0.14,0.07 -0.09,0.07 -0.21,0.15l-0.97 0.54c0,-1.87 0.15,-2.65 0.7,-4.26 0.82,-2.38 1.84,-3.58 3.09,-5.31l3.08 -3.4 5.16 -4.26c1.37,-0.89 2.7,-1.86 4.17,-2.67l0.76 -0.46c0.37,-0.23 1.2,-0.7 1.62,-0.87zm15.96 15.95l0 1.82 -0.37 3.99c-0.04,0.34 -0.15,0.76 -0.2,1.09 -0.05,0.36 -0.13,0.71 -0.21,1.02 -0.16,0.67 -0.35,1.31 -0.56,1.95 -0.1,0.31 -0.52,1.59 -0.75,1.73l-2.66 1.46c-0.12,0.07 -0.2,0.13 -0.32,0.19 -1.27,0.66 -1.04,0.52 -1.46,1.35 -0.38,0.75 -1,1.73 -1.48,2.26 -0.91,1.02 -0.87,0.95 -1.89,1.83 -1.09,0.78 -2.59,1.38 -4.15,1.7 -1.74,0.35 -3.64,0.3 -5.44,0.1 -2.32,-0.27 -5.12,-1.19 -7.26,-2.16 -1.88,-0.85 -3.31,-1.81 -4.96,-3.02l-1.58 -1.37c-0.62,-0.44 -0.71,-0.75 -1.06,-1.09l-1.6 -2.07c-1.54,-2.28 -2.22,-5.11 -1.71,-8.11 0.53,-3.12 2.04,-5.96 3.89,-8.47l1.61 -1.99c0.86,-0.95 3.48,-3.63 4.81,-4.61 0.17,-0.13 0.21,-0.21 0.38,-0.33l2.46 -1.86c0.56,-0.43 1.11,-0.78 1.7,-1.18 0.6,-0.4 1.18,-0.76 1.8,-1.15l0.9 -0.54c0.34,-0.18 0.59,-0.36 0.91,-0.52 0.53,-0.28 3.54,-1.92 3.67,-2.09l-1.58 -1.44 -1.76 -1.19c-0.31,-0.19 -0.66,-0.34 -1,-0.51 -3.99,-2 -8.26,-1.35 -12.21,0.18 -0.2,0.08 -0.33,0.14 -0.5,0.22 -0.26,0.11 -0.21,0.16 -0.5,0.22 -1.19,0.5 -2.53,1.3 -3.52,1.95 -0.59,0.39 -1.06,0.73 -1.6,1.13 -0.52,0.39 -1.05,0.81 -1.48,1.24 -0.02,0.01 -0.07,0.06 -0.08,0.07 -0.01,0.01 -0.04,0.05 -0.04,0.04 -0.01,-0.02 -0.02,0.02 -0.04,0.03 -0.28,-0.19 -0.3,-0.36 -0.51,-0.5 -0.17,-0.37 -1.39,-1.51 -1.66,-2.01 0.49,-0.51 1.5,-1.22 1.66,-1.44l2.05 -1.41c0.88,-0.59 1.48,-0.85 2.17,-1.28 0.28,-0.17 0.5,-0.26 0.75,-0.41 0.22,-0.13 0.42,-0.31 0.72,-0.33 0.41,-0.12 1.98,-0.87 2.95,-1.18 1.11,-0.35 2.16,-0.62 3.36,-0.83 2.39,-0.42 1.08,0.29 3.83,-1.31 0.14,-0.09 0.19,-0.1 0.33,-0.18 0.12,-0.06 0.25,-0.17 0.35,-0.22l0.8 -0.43c0.12,-0.06 0.03,-0.02 0.18,-0.1 0.29,-0.16 0.19,-0.04 0.33,-0.3 0.53,0 0.74,-0.08 1.24,-0.08 0.74,0 1.67,0.12 2.38,0.21 2.39,0.32 4.67,1.28 6.58,2.55 1.1,0.73 1.93,1.4 2.86,2.33l0.97 0.97c0.17,0.21 0.05,0.18 0.31,0.34 -0.22,0.28 -3.19,1.76 -3.57,2.08 1.12,-0.35 2.03,-0.87 2.99,-1.36l2.78 -1.58c0.19,-0.13 0.25,-0.19 0.52,-0.22 0.08,0.32 1.11,2.57 1.23,3.1l-1.73 0.93c0.05,0.21 0.12,0.29 0.22,0.43l1.8 3.31c1.38,3.06 2.25,5.72 2.97,9.03 0.49,2.24 0.89,5.4 0.98,8.02z"/>
  <path class="fil1" d="M130.88 11.94c-0.13,0.12 -0.6,0.35 -0.78,0.45 -1.96,1.02 -3.25,2.04 -5.56,2.54 -0.22,-0.01 -0.16,-0.01 -0.35,0.1 0.06,0.82 3.61,10.28 4.43,12.68l1.56 4.12c0.23,0.58 0.41,1.09 0.64,1.66l2.33 5.73c0.12,0.3 0.2,0.52 0.34,0.81l3.21 7.07c0.26,0.52 0.47,1.11 0.74,1.55 0.17,0.28 0.27,0.48 0.41,0.75l1.2 2.25c0.09,0.19 0.11,0.21 0.21,0.37l1.26 2.11c0.09,0.14 0.13,0.23 0.22,0.36 0.73,1.13 1.21,1.7 1.93,2.68l0.52 0.63c0.2,0.21 0.39,0.35 0.55,0.59 0.17,0.23 0.39,0.35 0.6,0.56 1.4,1.42 3.73,2.47 5.69,1.41 0.16,-0.09 0.18,-0.12 0.35,-0.22 0.16,-0.09 0.04,0 0.18,-0.11l0.11 -0.1c0,0 0.02,-0.02 0.03,-0.03 0.43,-0.54 0.67,-0.5 1.46,-1.79 0.42,-0.67 0.78,-1.48 1.06,-2.26 0.13,-0.33 0.16,-0.29 0.96,-0.7l3.23 -1.76 0.16 -0.3c0.06,-0.15 0.1,-0.26 0.15,-0.43 0.09,-0.3 0.18,-0.58 0.25,-0.83 0.16,-0.6 0.33,-1.15 0.45,-1.78l0.96 -5.58c0.19,-1.08 0.28,-2.34 0.4,-3.41l0.14 -2.09c0.02,-0.27 0.07,-0.18 0.08,-0.5l0.21 -4.17c0.01,-0.4 0.07,-0.15 0.07,-1.01l0.08 -2.08c-0.01,-0.87 0.06,-0.69 0.07,-1.08 0.03,-0.7 -0.01,-1.45 -0.01,-2.16 0.01,-0.37 0.08,-0.55 0.08,-1l-0.01 -5.54c-0.17,-0.37 -1.39,-1.51 -1.66,-2.01 0.49,-0.51 1.5,-1.22 1.66,-1.44l0.01 -3.45c0,-0.49 -0.07,-0.67 -0.07,-1.08 0,-0.77 0,-1.54 0,-2.3 0,-0.48 -0.07,-0.71 -0.08,-1.08 0,-0.38 0.01,-0.77 0.01,-1.15 0,-1.48 -0.15,-2.99 -0.15,-4.46 0,-0.82 -0.07,-1.39 -0.07,-2.23 0,-0.48 -0.07,-0.66 -0.07,-1.08 0,-0.38 0,-0.77 0,-1.15l-0.15 0c-0.74,0 -1.47,0 -2.21,0l-0.19 0c-0.57,0 -0.48,0.05 -1.12,0.43l-3.52 1.94 0.14 3.31c0,0.62 0.07,1 0.07,1.65l0.08 1.66c-0.02,3.19 0.21,6.89 0.21,10.14l0 9.49c0,0.41 -0.07,0.46 -0.07,0.86 0,0.58 0,1.15 0,1.73l-0.07 2.52c0,0.45 -0.08,0.76 -0.08,1.65 0.01,0.4 -0.05,0.5 -0.07,0.79 -0.02,0.26 0.01,0.59 0.01,0.87 -0.01,0.36 -0.08,0.39 -0.08,0.78 0,0.33 0.01,0.52 -0.04,0.82l-0.18 2.42c0,0.39 -0.05,0.51 -0.07,0.79 -0.25,3.76 -0.76,7.62 -1.74,11.28 -0.11,0.42 -0.31,0.93 -0.41,1.38 -1.24,-0.83 -3.66,-4.57 -4.49,-6.09 -0.07,-0.14 -0.09,-0.2 -0.17,-0.33l-0.88 -1.57c-0.73,-1.24 -2.47,-4.99 -3.16,-6.54 -0.21,-0.44 -0.41,-0.84 -0.61,-1.34 -0.06,-0.14 -0.08,-0.15 -0.14,-0.29l-1.03 -2.42c-0.2,-0.47 -0.38,-0.88 -0.58,-1.36 -0.38,-0.95 -0.73,-1.81 -1.12,-2.76l-1.35 -3.47c-0.08,-0.23 -0.2,-0.47 -0.29,-0.72 -0.08,-0.23 -0.16,-0.41 -0.25,-0.68 -0.52,-1.52 -1.3,-3.36 -1.85,-4.98 -0.18,-0.51 -0.33,-0.93 -0.52,-1.42 -0.1,-0.25 -0.16,-0.48 -0.24,-0.7l-1.27 -3.62c-0.21,-0.61 -1.44,-3.98 -1.47,-4.36l-0.28 0.08z"/>
  <path class="fil2" d="M24.08 34.16c-0.18,-0.14 -0.38,-0.28 -0.55,-0.45 -0.1,-0.1 -0.16,-0.15 -0.25,-0.25l-0.71 -0.8c-0.79,-1 -1.28,-1.55 -2.02,-2.66 -0.1,-0.16 -0.14,-0.18 -0.24,-0.33 -0.16,-0.21 -0.26,-0.39 -0.41,-0.6l-2.76 -4.57c-0.14,-0.26 -0.22,-0.39 -0.36,-0.65 -0.1,-0.18 -0.1,-0.14 -0.19,-0.31l-0.39 -0.7c-0.84,-1.54 -2.85,-4.89 -3.88,-6.03 -0.67,-0.74 -1.39,-1.41 -2.47,-1.72 -4.18,-0.44 -4.58,5.49 -4.78,8.48 -0.5,7.21 0.5,18.12 1.19,25.47 0.38,4.06 0.93,8.08 1.33,12.15l2.91 -0.5c0.27,-0.07 0.26,-0.12 0.19,-0.47 -0.19,-1 -0.3,-2.7 -0.46,-3.79l-0.81 -7.6c-0.02,-0.42 -0.07,-0.88 -0.13,-1.24 -0.07,-0.44 -0.03,-0.91 -0.1,-1.34 -0.12,-0.78 -0.14,-1.77 -0.26,-2.54l-0.58 -7.83c-0.11,-0.87 0.03,-1.85 -0.12,-2.69l-0.11 -8.31c0.02,-0.27 0.08,-0.28 0.08,-0.65 0,-0.99 0.13,-1.48 0.14,-2.01 -0.04,-0.91 0.43,-3.22 0.87,-3.79 0.94,0.45 2.91,3.85 3.63,5.11 1.44,2.53 3.27,5.83 4.91,8.19 0.31,0.45 0.6,0.9 0.92,1.3 0.18,0.23 0.3,0.41 0.46,0.62 0.18,0.25 0.31,0.37 0.48,0.6l2.1 2.29c0.18,0.2 0.37,0.29 0.58,0.5 0.16,0.15 0.39,0.31 0.6,0.48 0.33,0.25 1,0.62 1.26,0.88 0.28,0.22 0.62,0.31 0.92,0.45 2.27,1.07 4.42,0.96 6.66,0 0.49,-0.2 1.71,-0.97 2.08,-1.3 0.6,-0.51 1.32,-1.04 1.8,-1.65l0.63 -0.74c0.67,-0.91 0.99,-1.19 1.76,-2.34l1.56 -2.53c0.45,-0.71 0.78,-1.47 1.19,-2.2 0.49,-0.89 0.97,-1.79 1.36,-2.73 0.08,-0.18 0.16,-0.32 0.24,-0.48l1.32 -2.78c0.64,-1.26 1.03,-2.28 1.78,-3.69 0.22,-0.67 0.91,-1.82 1.26,-2.41 0.43,-0.73 1.08,-1.75 1.68,-2.08 1.44,0.82 2.22,7.73 2.43,9.88 0.67,6.96 0.78,16.86 0.65,23.95 -0.04,1.97 -0.1,3.99 -0.11,5.96 -0.01,2.02 -0.16,4.05 -0.16,6.05 0.15,0.18 0.11,-0.01 0.72,-0.01l1.8 0.01c0.75,0 0.65,0.18 0.64,-1.16 0,-0.42 0.07,-0.49 0.08,-0.86 0,-0.62 -0.01,-1.25 -0.01,-1.87l0.08 -1.72c0,-0.51 -0.06,-1.31 0.02,-1.77 0.15,-0.79 0.05,-2.7 0.05,-3.63 0,-0.6 0.07,-1.05 0.07,-1.72l0 -9.06c0,-1.23 -0.07,-2.31 -0.07,-3.6l-0.07 -2.59c0,-0.42 -0.07,-0.49 -0.08,-0.86 -0.01,-1.24 -0.12,-2.33 -0.14,-3.53l-1.12 -9.73c-0.23,-1.15 -0.73,-3.25 -1.23,-4.24 -0.06,-0.13 -0.08,-0.15 -0.14,-0.29 -0.42,-1.01 -1.47,-2.36 -2.61,-2.49 -1.99,-0.24 -3.09,0.82 -4.21,2.34 -1.63,2.24 -4.3,8.07 -5.61,10.93 -0.98,2.14 -2.3,4.51 -3.51,6.49 -0.42,0.69 -0.88,1.33 -1.36,1.94 -2.09,2.7 -4.95,5.2 -8.52,3.23 -0.56,-0.31 -1.62,-1.03 -1.9,-1.41z"/>
  <path class="fil3" d="M71.39 54.65c-1.16,-0.62 -1.96,-1.23 -2.95,-2.07 -0.86,-0.73 -0.95,-0.87 -1.69,-1.62 -0.09,-0.08 -0.13,-0.12 -0.22,-0.21 -0.91,-0.95 -1.84,-2.51 -2.39,-3.72 -1.37,-3.01 -0.49,-6.06 1.25,-8.67 0.15,-0.22 0.23,-0.35 0.38,-0.57 0.55,-0.81 1.4,-1.8 2.09,-2.5 1.86,-1.86 3.43,-3.19 5.63,-4.66 1.97,-1.3 4.44,-2.7 6.57,-3.71l1.94 -0.87c0.22,-0.09 0.42,-0.18 0.65,-0.28l2 -0.81c0.25,-0.09 0.39,-0.2 0.69,-0.22l1.88 -0.73c0.6,-0.21 1.33,-0.47 1.94,-0.62 1.5,3.18 2.2,8.87 2.13,12.49 -0.1,4.55 -0.75,8.43 -2.14,12.42 -1.23,3.51 -3.46,7.11 -6.34,8.27 -1.93,0.78 -4.21,0.72 -6.29,0.22 -1.25,-0.3 -4.22,-1.35 -5.13,-2.14zm-7.84 -35.81l0.08 0.08c0.14,-0.19 0.52,-0.39 0.73,-0.51l2.54 -1.34c2.34,-1.19 6.48,-2.46 8.96,-2.55l2.53 0.06c0.22,0.04 0.43,0.05 0.58,0.07 0.23,0.04 0.4,0.06 0.56,0.07 1.9,0.29 3.6,1.2 4.83,2.1 0.64,0.46 0.52,0.45 0.94,0.78 0.63,0.5 1.92,2.08 2.32,2.82 -0.16,0.12 -2.98,1.07 -3.46,1.24 -1.15,0.43 -2.26,0.87 -3.37,1.38 -2.21,1.01 -4.34,2.02 -6.31,3.19 -2.07,1.23 -3.89,2.5 -5.63,3.87l-1.28 1.08c-0.77,0.6 -1.79,1.78 -2.38,2.37 -0.13,0.13 -0.17,0.13 -0.29,0.28 -0.11,0.13 -0.14,0.21 -0.26,0.33 -0.22,0.23 -0.34,0.37 -0.53,0.61 -0.35,0.43 -0.66,0.88 -1.01,1.36 -0.92,1.27 -1.89,3.26 -2.34,4.79 -1.17,4.04 0.08,7.78 2.41,10.89 0.55,0.74 0.72,0.85 1.08,1.29 0.93,1.14 1.02,1.06 1.8,1.8 0.23,0.21 0.34,0.32 0.6,0.55l0.69 0.53c1.12,0.9 3.3,2.08 3.53,2.27 1.2,0.77 4.86,1.87 6.16,2.07 0.61,0.09 1.18,0.16 1.85,0.15 3.01,0 5.07,-0.43 7.47,-2.31 0.15,-0.12 0.16,-0.1 0.32,-0.26 0.21,-0.2 0.33,-0.26 0.54,-0.46l2.69 -3.42 0.75 -1.34c1.91,-3.82 3.26,-8.62 3.55,-12.92 0.02,-0.28 0.05,-0.14 0.07,-0.43 0.15,-2.14 0.14,-3.42 0.15,-5.53 0,-0.46 -0.08,-0.64 -0.08,-1.01l-0.14 -1.87c-0.09,-1.84 -1.17,-6.8 -1.94,-8.41 0.45,-0.11 1.62,-0.47 2.01,-0.51l-0.5 -3.16c-0.1,-0.11 0.02,-0.04 -0.15,-0.04l-2.79 0.69c-0.23,-0.49 -0.57,-1 -0.84,-1.4l-0.9 -1.26 -1.42 -1.53c-0.91,-0.92 -2.24,-1.89 -3.42,-2.48 -0.38,-0.18 -1.78,-0.85 -2.13,-0.88 -0.91,-0.22 -1.66,-0.47 -2.66,-0.59 -4.76,-0.56 -8.97,0.64 -13.25,2.51 -0.85,0.37 -3.59,1.71 -4.15,2.25 0.21,0.6 1.26,2.14 1.49,2.73z"/>
  <path class="fil4" d="M110.02 60.47l2.66 -1.15 -2.63 -7.79c-0.41,-1.2 -2.12,-7.55 -2.19,-8.31 -0.27,-0.69 -0.52,-2.28 -0.69,-3.12 -0.29,-1.44 -1.63,-8.64 -1.61,-9.61 -0.13,-0.27 -0.61,-4.53 -0.71,-5.47 -0.04,-0.31 -0.03,-1.11 -0.12,-1.61 -0.07,-0.36 0.01,-0.73 -0.06,-1.09 -0.12,-0.65 -0.13,-4.13 0.01,-5 0.03,-0.2 0,-0.38 0.02,-0.57l0.45 -3c0.47,-2.29 1.63,-4.71 3.23,-5.9 1.42,-1.06 3.04,-1.82 4.88,-1.95 0.49,-0.04 0.2,-0.08 1.07,-0.08 0.36,0 0.88,0.06 1.08,0.05 2.66,0.32 5.42,1.91 6.17,3.85 0.95,2.41 -1.13,5.8 -2.1,7.36 -2.2,3.54 -5.95,8.45 -7.65,12.2 -2.53,5.62 -2.95,10.23 0.56,15.45 0.74,1.1 1.38,1.71 2.31,2.65 0.8,0.81 1.77,1.61 2.69,2.27 0.91,0.66 1.93,1.33 3,1.96l3.22 1.75c0.25,0.21 1.44,0.65 1.77,0.81 1.28,0.61 2.37,1.01 3.67,1.52l0.93 0.35c0.33,0.13 0.62,0.26 0.96,0.34 0.03,-0.3 0.38,-1.1 0.5,-1.45l0.51 -1.43c-0.53,-0.13 -2.25,-0.97 -2.88,-1.21l-1.91 -0.83c-0.6,-0.26 -1.27,-0.41 -1.97,-0.77 -2.09,-1.05 -5.04,-2.57 -6.81,-4.11 -1.31,-1.14 -0.85,-0.63 -2.19,-1.98 -0.48,-0.47 -0.85,-0.94 -1.26,-1.47 -0.21,-0.27 -0.36,-0.53 -0.55,-0.82 -2.45,-3.67 -1.87,-8.03 0.03,-11.82l3.55 -6.01 4.34 -6.59c0.89,-1.42 1.68,-3.17 2.13,-4.77 0.55,-1.97 0.28,-3.98 -0.7,-5.69 -0.09,-0.16 -0.15,-0.26 -0.25,-0.4 -1.11,-1.45 -2.57,-2.57 -4.28,-3.26 -0.36,-0.15 -0.7,-0.3 -1.05,-0.39 -0.73,-0.15 -1.37,-0.4 -2.16,-0.5 -2.41,-0.29 -4.49,0.1 -6.62,1 -2.47,1.03 -4.2,2.74 -5.4,4.96 -3.77,6.99 -1.91,19.08 -0.48,27.1 1.22,6.81 1.93,10.22 3.88,16.83 0.39,1.29 0.83,2.62 1.28,3.9l1.37 3.8z"/>
  <path class="fil5" d="M110.02 60.47l-1.37 -3.8c-0.45,-1.28 -0.89,-2.61 -1.28,-3.9 -1.95,-6.61 -2.66,-10.02 -3.88,-16.83 -1.43,-8.02 -3.29,-20.11 0.48,-27.1 1.2,-2.22 2.93,-3.93 5.4,-4.96 2.13,-0.9 4.21,-1.29 6.62,-1 0.79,0.1 1.43,0.35 2.16,0.5 -0.02,-0.01 -0.04,-0.05 -0.04,-0.04 -0.01,0.02 -0.03,-0.02 -0.04,-0.03 -0.12,-0.06 -0.04,-0.02 -0.15,-0.07l-3.97 -1.7c-1.24,-0.49 -3.79,-1.09 -5.11,-0.85l-1.35 0.16c-0.49,0.08 -0.8,0.13 -1.25,0.26 -0.72,0.2 -2.11,0.71 -2.69,1.05l-0.5 0.29c-0.14,0.08 -0.3,0.19 -0.44,0.28 -0.15,0.11 -0.31,0.19 -0.47,0.32l-0.59 0.49c-0.29,0.27 -0.59,0.4 -1.02,0.99 -0.45,0.63 -0.59,0.55 -1.27,1.75 -0.31,0.54 -0.79,1.45 -0.99,2.03 -0.54,1.63 -1.06,3.1 -1.19,4.92l-0.22 2.01c-0.01,0.25 0.02,0.55 0,0.8l-0.07 1.43c0,0.51 0,1.01 0,1.51l1.12 11.04 0.88 5.22c0.51,3.3 1.32,6.8 2.13,10.03 0.79,3.19 2.59,9.12 4.02,12.67 0.2,0.49 -0.04,0.41 0.77,0.73l3.17 1.36c0.23,0.09 0.32,0.15 0.55,0.24 0.23,0.09 0.3,0.18 0.59,0.2z"/>
  <path class="fil6" d="M70.87 58.25c-0.23,-0.19 -2.41,-1.37 -3.53,-2.27l-0.69 -0.53c-0.26,-0.23 -0.37,-0.34 -0.6,-0.55 -0.78,-0.74 -0.87,-0.66 -1.8,-1.8 -0.36,-0.44 -0.53,-0.55 -1.08,-1.29 -2.33,-3.11 -3.58,-6.85 -2.41,-10.89 0.45,-1.53 1.42,-3.52 2.34,-4.79 0.35,-0.48 0.66,-0.93 1.01,-1.36 0.19,-0.24 0.31,-0.38 0.53,-0.61 0.12,-0.12 0.15,-0.2 0.26,-0.33 0.12,-0.15 0.16,-0.15 0.29,-0.28 0.59,-0.59 1.61,-1.77 2.38,-2.37l1.28 -1.08c1.74,-1.37 3.56,-2.64 5.63,-3.87 1.97,-1.17 4.1,-2.18 6.31,-3.19 1.11,-0.51 2.22,-0.95 3.37,-1.38 0.48,-0.17 3.3,-1.12 3.46,-1.24 -0.4,-0.74 -1.69,-2.32 -2.32,-2.82 -0.42,-0.33 -0.3,-0.32 -0.94,-0.78 -1.23,-0.9 -2.93,-1.81 -4.83,-2.1 0.12,0.2 1.24,1.02 1.74,1.66 0.09,0.12 0.04,0.09 0.15,0.21l1.27 1.75c-0.31,0.07 -0.61,0.19 -0.92,0.29 -2.01,0.67 -5.17,1.87 -6.96,2.75 -1.12,0.56 -2.41,1.08 -3.48,1.7 -0.15,0.09 -0.2,0.14 -0.4,0.24 -1.76,0.87 -5.22,3.21 -6.66,4.35 -0.07,0.06 -0.07,0.08 -0.15,0.14l-0.9 0.75c-0.17,0.14 -0.18,0.12 -0.35,0.29 -0.17,0.17 -0.2,0.16 -0.36,0.29l-1.96 1.92c-0.2,0.28 -0.42,0.42 -0.63,0.67 -0.14,0.16 -0.12,0.19 -0.29,0.36 -0.17,0.17 -0.16,0.18 -0.29,0.35l-0.29 0.36c-2.67,3.39 -4.61,7.64 -3.28,12.1 0.39,1.28 1.27,3.23 2.14,4.34l2.37 2.81c0.16,0.15 0.2,0.14 0.36,0.28l1.36 1.22c1.95,1.64 4.7,3 7.06,3.95l0.91 0.39c0.19,0.08 0.69,0.33 0.9,0.36z"/>
  <path class="fil7" d="M7.59 61.19c-0.4,-4.07 -0.95,-8.09 -1.33,-12.15 -0.69,-7.35 -1.69,-18.26 -1.19,-25.47 0.2,-2.99 0.6,-8.92 4.78,-8.48 -0.13,-0.1 -0.1,-0.08 -0.28,-0.14 -0.13,-0.06 -0.19,-0.09 -0.34,-0.16l-2.62 -1.12c-0.26,-0.1 -0.42,-0.2 -0.65,-0.29 -0.46,-0.17 -0.88,-0.44 -1.5,-0.44 -1.25,0 -2.01,0.53 -2.55,1.27 -0.28,0.38 -0.51,0.75 -0.68,1.19 -0.48,1.24 -1,3.47 -1.02,4.73 -0.01,0.86 -0.21,2.3 -0.21,3.6l0.07 6.54c0,0.84 0.05,0.54 0.08,0.94 0.02,0.28 -0.01,0.64 -0.01,0.94l1.92 21.81c0.03,0.18 0.01,0.23 0.03,0.4 0.09,1.31 0.46,3.46 0.57,4.75 0.48,0.11 4.19,1.79 4.93,2.08z"/>
  <path class="fil7" d="M45.45 18.41c0.09,0 0.45,3.48 0.5,3.89 0.03,0.33 0.03,1.1 0.13,1.73 0.03,0.21 0,0.43 0.01,0.64 0.01,0.32 0.07,0.25 0.08,0.57 0.01,0.21 -0.02,0.44 -0.01,0.65 0.02,0.41 0.08,0.33 0.08,1.22 0,0.34 0.04,0.35 0.06,0.58 0.05,0.35 -0.01,0.85 0.01,1.22 0.01,0.4 0.07,0.34 0.07,1.22 0,0.9 0.07,1.53 0.07,2.44 0,1.71 0.07,3.28 0.07,5.04l0.01 8.84c0,0.43 -0.08,0.71 -0.08,1.23 0,1.76 -0.07,3.33 -0.07,5.03 0,1.51 -0.14,3.45 -0.14,4.96 0.43,0.1 2.21,0.93 2.78,1.17 0.12,0.06 0.2,0.08 0.31,0.12l1.87 0.8c0,-2 0.15,-4.03 0.16,-6.05 0.01,-1.97 0.07,-3.99 0.11,-5.96 0.13,-7.09 0.02,-16.99 -0.65,-23.95 -0.21,-2.15 -0.99,-9.06 -2.43,-9.88 -0.6,0.33 -1.25,1.35 -1.68,2.08 -0.35,0.59 -1.04,1.74 -1.26,2.41z"/>
  <path class="fil8" d="M105.56 30.49c-0.02,0.97 1.32,8.17 1.61,9.61 0.17,0.84 0.42,2.43 0.69,3.12 0.1,0.07 0.29,0.3 0.38,0.41 0.57,0.74 1.26,1.45 1.98,2.05 1.05,0.89 1.43,1.34 2.7,2.18l2.95 1.87c0.2,0.12 0.33,0.16 0.52,0.27 0.22,0.14 0.32,0.19 0.56,0.31l5.48 2.57c0.34,0.14 0.86,0.45 1.18,0.48l-3.22 -1.75c-1.07,-0.63 -2.09,-1.3 -3,-1.96 -0.92,-0.66 -1.89,-1.46 -2.69,-2.27 -0.93,-0.94 -1.57,-1.55 -2.31,-2.65 -3.51,-5.22 -3.09,-9.83 -0.56,-15.45 1.7,-3.75 5.45,-8.66 7.65,-12.2 0.97,-1.56 3.05,-4.95 2.1,-7.36 -0.75,-1.94 -3.51,-3.53 -6.17,-3.85 0.9,1.01 1.44,1.45 1.44,3.19 0,2.28 -1.92,5.37 -3.21,7.29 -0.17,0.26 -0.3,0.46 -0.46,0.69l-2.84 4.2c-1.87,2.81 -3.68,5.76 -4.66,9.01l-0.12 0.24z"/>
  <path class="fil9" d="M85.34 24.74l0.5 2.39c0.08,0.46 0.11,0.79 0.17,1.27l0.21 2.02c-0.01,0.36 0.04,0.41 0.07,0.65 0.04,0.37 0,1.03 0,1.43 0,0.26 -0.01,0.44 0.03,0.7l-0.03 2.11c0,0.35 -0.04,0.41 -0.07,0.65 -0.02,0.22 0.02,0.49 -0.01,0.71 -0.04,0.4 -0.1,0.85 -0.14,1.3 -0.24,3.43 -1.67,8.31 -3.25,11.34l-0.53 0.91c-0.77,1.34 -2.19,3.01 -3.5,3.76 -1.71,0.98 -2.75,1.03 -4.8,1.03 -0.49,0 -0.87,-0.03 -1.32,-0.11l-1.28 -0.25c0.91,0.79 3.88,1.84 5.13,2.14 2.08,0.5 4.36,0.56 6.29,-0.22 2.88,-1.16 5.11,-4.76 6.34,-8.27 1.39,-3.99 2.04,-7.87 2.14,-12.42 0.07,-3.62 -0.63,-9.31 -2.13,-12.49 -0.61,0.15 -1.34,0.41 -1.94,0.62l-1.88 0.73z"/>
  <path class="fil10" d="M24.08 34.16c0.28,0.38 1.34,1.1 1.9,1.41 3.57,1.97 6.43,-0.53 8.52,-3.23 0.48,-0.61 0.94,-1.25 1.36,-1.94 1.21,-1.98 2.53,-4.35 3.51,-6.49 1.31,-2.86 3.98,-8.69 5.61,-10.93 1.12,-1.52 2.22,-2.58 4.21,-2.34 -0.02,-0.01 -0.04,-0.05 -0.04,-0.04l-0.49 -0.22c-0.21,-0.09 -0.39,-0.17 -0.6,-0.26l-2.3 -1.01c-1.27,-0.54 -2.35,-1.1 -3.85,-0.14 -0.43,0.28 -0.56,0.41 -0.9,0.76 -1.4,1.39 -1.74,2.32 -2.68,3.93 -0.11,0.18 -0.19,0.3 -0.29,0.51l-2.95 6.18c-0.18,0.37 -0.33,0.74 -0.53,1.13 -0.38,0.76 -0.72,1.44 -1.1,2.2l-0.84 1.61c-0.12,0.21 -0.16,0.36 -0.29,0.57l-0.89 1.55c-0.55,0.86 -1.38,2.22 -2.01,2.95 -0.34,0.4 -1.22,1.5 -1.56,1.75 -0.85,0.64 -1.45,1.45 -3.07,1.89 -0.25,0.07 -0.53,0.07 -0.72,0.16z"/>
  <path class="fil11" d="M63.55 18.84c-0.23,-0.59 -1.28,-2.13 -1.49,-2.73 0.56,-0.54 3.3,-1.88 4.15,-2.25 4.28,-1.87 8.49,-3.07 13.25,-2.51 1,0.12 1.75,0.37 2.66,0.59l-0.32 -0.19c-0.17,-0.07 -0.19,-0.07 -0.35,-0.15 -0.24,-0.12 -0.47,-0.21 -0.7,-0.31l-2.88 -1.21c-1.6,-0.56 -1.49,-0.52 -3.27,-0.83 -2.4,-0.42 -5.94,-0.01 -8.2,0.63 -0.3,0.08 -0.54,0.14 -0.85,0.23l-4.43 1.68c-0.55,0.28 -1.51,0.67 -2.07,1.02l-2.03 1.14 1.54 2.71c0.15,0.18 1.6,0.73 1.96,0.91 0.34,0.17 0.66,0.27 1.01,0.43l2.02 0.84z"/>
  <path class="fil7" d="M8.34 22.22l0.53 0.91c0.09,0.17 0.11,0.18 0.19,0.31 0.07,0.12 0.09,0.2 0.17,0.33 1.32,2.16 2.03,3.52 3.61,5.88l1.49 2.04c0.12,0.14 0.1,0.16 0.21,0.29l0.65 0.79c0.08,0.1 0.16,0.16 0.25,0.25 0.1,0.1 0.17,0.16 0.25,0.26 0.61,0.78 0.9,0.92 1.51,1.51 0.15,0.14 0.15,0.11 0.29,0.22 0.11,0.08 0.15,0.15 0.26,0.24 0.09,0.07 0.19,0.14 0.29,0.21 0.64,0.49 1.15,0.78 1.88,1.14 1.14,0.57 2.77,1.16 3.86,1.68 0.17,0.08 0.15,0.1 0.37,0.12 -0.26,-0.26 -0.93,-0.63 -1.26,-0.88 -0.21,-0.17 -0.44,-0.33 -0.6,-0.48 -0.21,-0.21 -0.4,-0.3 -0.58,-0.5l-2.1 -2.29c-0.17,-0.23 -0.3,-0.35 -0.48,-0.6 -0.16,-0.21 -0.28,-0.39 -0.46,-0.62 -0.32,-0.4 -0.61,-0.85 -0.92,-1.3 -1.64,-2.36 -3.47,-5.66 -4.91,-8.19 -0.72,-1.26 -2.69,-4.66 -3.63,-5.11 -0.44,0.57 -0.91,2.88 -0.87,3.79z"/>
  <path class="fil12" d="M170.49 43.04c-0.34,-1.13 0.49,-3.85 0.99,-5.02 1,-2.36 1.9,-3.33 3.23,-5.11 0.74,-1 2.14,-2.34 3.03,-3.23l2.23 -1.94c0.2,-0.19 0.34,-0.27 0.56,-0.44 0.82,-0.62 1.47,-1.18 2.39,-1.79l1.85 -1.24c0.26,-0.23 -0.05,0.17 0.11,-0.16 -0.42,0.17 -1.25,0.64 -1.62,0.87l-0.76 0.46c-1.47,0.81 -2.8,1.78 -4.17,2.67l-5.16 4.26 -3.08 3.4c-1.25,1.73 -2.27,2.93 -3.09,5.31 -0.55,1.61 -0.7,2.39 -0.7,4.26l0.97 -0.54c0.12,-0.08 0.07,-0.08 0.21,-0.15 0.49,-0.26 2.74,-1.56 3.01,-1.61z"/>
  <path class="fil13" d="M150.7 59.9c0.29,-0.06 3.06,-1.67 3.4,-1.87l0.79 -0.5c1.04,-0.76 2.52,-3.37 2.52,-4.14l-3.23 1.76c-0.8,0.41 -0.83,0.37 -0.96,0.7 -0.28,0.78 -0.64,1.59 -1.06,2.26 -0.79,1.29 -1.03,1.25 -1.46,1.79z"/>
  <path class="fil14" d="M190.94 58.75c0.24,-0.07 0.33,-0.18 0.55,-0.29l1.8 -1.01c0.22,-0.11 0.34,-0.2 0.6,-0.33 0.23,-0.11 0.37,-0.21 0.59,-0.34 0.76,-0.46 1.51,-1.02 2.06,-1.68l0.87 -1.01c0.34,-0.44 1.24,-1.85 1.34,-2.43l-2.66 1.46c-0.12,0.07 -0.2,0.13 -0.32,0.19 -1.27,0.66 -1.04,0.52 -1.46,1.35 -0.38,0.75 -1,1.73 -1.48,2.26 -0.91,1.02 -0.87,0.95 -1.89,1.83z"/>
  <path class="fil15" d="M166.18 14.55c0.41,-0.12 1.98,-0.87 2.95,-1.18 1.11,-0.35 2.16,-0.62 3.36,-0.83 2.39,-0.42 1.08,0.29 3.83,-1.31 0.14,-0.09 0.19,-0.1 0.33,-0.18 0.12,-0.06 0.25,-0.17 0.35,-0.22l0.8 -0.43c0.12,-0.06 0.03,-0.02 0.18,-0.1 0.29,-0.16 0.19,-0.04 0.33,-0.3 -0.52,0 -1.29,0.13 -1.84,0.22 -2.98,0.46 -6.4,2 -8.99,3.52l-0.97 0.54c-0.28,0.14 -0.2,0.05 -0.33,0.27z"/>
  <path class="fil16" d="M93.62 18.8l-0.52 -0.3c-0.57,-0.26 -3.76,-1.65 -4.01,-1.67l0.9 1.26c0.27,0.4 0.61,0.91 0.84,1.4l2.79 -0.69z"/>
  <path class="fil17" d="M161.16 21.79l3.92 -2.18 1.15 -0.93c0.24,-0.2 1.4,-1.01 1.53,-1.21 -1.19,0.5 -2.53,1.3 -3.52,1.95 -0.59,0.39 -1.06,0.73 -1.6,1.13 -0.52,0.39 -1.05,0.81 -1.48,1.24z"/>
  <path class="fil18" d="M124.54 14.93c2.31,-0.5 3.6,-1.52 5.56,-2.54 0.18,-0.1 0.65,-0.33 0.78,-0.45l-3.33 1.2 -2.93 1.6c-0.04,0.04 -0.05,0.13 -0.08,0.19z"/>
  <path class="fil17" d="M192.65 16.32c-0.22,0.28 -3.19,1.76 -3.57,2.08 1.12,-0.35 2.03,-0.87 2.99,-1.36l2.78 -1.58c-0.22,0.02 -0.86,0.3 -1.08,0.41 -0.19,0.09 -0.39,0.16 -0.56,0.23 -0.23,0.09 -0.34,0.17 -0.56,0.22z"/>
 </g>
  </SvgIcon>
);
```

Comment: En que sitio o despues de que elemento quieres cargar la imagen?

Comment: @Suso En el espacio que esta arriba de la opción "Dashboard" donde se ve el icono de cierre, en ese espacio en blanco.

Comment: @ArmandoVázquez, esta difícil darte una respuesta sin poder probar. Me parece (_no estoy seguro_) que la imagen debería ir antes o después de `<ChevronLeftIcon />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes la imagen guardadada? primero importa tu archivo svg

```
import { SvgIcon } from "@material-ui/core";
```

crea una constante fuera del makeStyles y pon la url de tu logo

```
    const LogoIcon = (props) => (
     <SvgIcon {...props}>
      <image href="URL_DEL_LOGOTIPO.svg" />
     </SvgIcon>
    );
```

despues dentro de tu funcion principal del componente en luga de ScgIcon usa LogoIcon, remplazalo.
te dejo codigo donde deberia darte algo de solucion

```
   <Typography
    component="h1"
    variant="h6"
    color="inherit"
    noWrap
    className={classes.title}
   >
   <LogoIcon className={classes.logo} /> {/* Reemplaza SvgIcon con LogoIcon 
   */}
   titulo de tu app
   </Typography>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";

import {
  makeStyles,
  Drawer,
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  List,
  Typography,
  Divider,
  MenuItem,
  IconButton,
  Menu,
  SvgIcon, // Agrega SvgIcon de Material-UI //
} from "@material-ui/core";

import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import AccountCircle from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";

import MainListItems from "./MainListItems";
import NotificationsPopOver from "../components/NotificationsPopOver";
import UserModal from "../components/UserModal";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/Auth/AuthContext";
import BackdropLoading from "../components/BackdropLoading";
import { i18n } from "../translate/i18n";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    height: "100vh",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      height: "calc(100vh - 56px)",
    },
  },

  toolbar: {
    paddingRight: 24, // keep right padding when drawer closed
  },
  toolbarIcon: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: "0 8px",
    minHeight: "48px",
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: 36,
  },
  menuButtonHidden: {
    display: "none",
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    position: "relative",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  drawerPaperClose: {
    overflowX: "hidden",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    width: theme.spacing(7),
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: theme.spacing(9),
    },
  },
  appBarSpacer: {
    minHeight: "48px",
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    overflow: "auto",
  },
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    display: "flex",
    overflow: "auto",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  logo: { // Agrega estilos para el logo
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

// Defini tu icono SVG como un componente de React //
const LogoIcon = (props) => (
  <SvgIcon {...
```

Proba de esta forma, espero que te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Hola Armando! No, no podes agregarlo para poder utilizar una imagen como un icono en React, es necesario importarla y luego utilizarla como un componente. No es posible simplemente agregar un link de la imagen y utilizarla como un icono.

Comment: O como sería usando en vez de un SVG una PNG común? es más sencillo?

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisar [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Al final si te creaste un componente donde vas a tener tu foto del logo puedes manejar obtener la imagen con la etiqueta `<img>`. Puedes en el componente ponerlo de la siguiente forma

```
<img
   className="h-36 w-36 rounded-full "
   src={
         imageUrl ? imageUrl : DefaultImageUrl
       } alt="logo"
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

puedes usar una imagen agregandole al atributo src la url relativa o absoluta. Vamos que si la  tienes descargada puede ser una ruta local o poner el enlace que sea.

```
<div classname="clase-imagen" onClick={()=>console.log("pulsado")}>
    <img src="https://fldasfjlasdfsal.com" />
</div>
```

Luego darle las propiedades que desees al componente div ya sea ancho, alto, etc. También le puedes agregar el evento onclick para que haga algo cuando lo pulses...

Comment: Entiendo, pero eso en un PHP o HTML es super facil, el problema es que en React me parece no es igual, porque si lo intente y no logre hacer que funcionara.